# Angular 2 NgTemplateOutlet with string variable.

Tags: angular

I would like to have a string of a template in the .ts-file and add it to the NgTemplateOutlet.

I was hoping this would work but it did not.

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="$implicit">
```

where template is a string-variable in the scope. So I implemented this, however this does not work as I wanted it to either.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
 selector: 'dynamic-report',
 templateUrl: 'dynamicReport.html',
})
export class DynamicReport implements AfterViewInit{
 private _template: string;
 context: any;

 public get template() : SafeHtml {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._template);
 }

 constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController, public modalCtrl:ModalController, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this._template = "<button (click)='testFunction1('2')'>Click here 2!</button>";
   this.context = this;

 }

  testFunction1(message){
    console.log(message);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="report" [ngOutletContext]="$implicit">

</template>
<template #report>
  <button (click)='testFunction1("1")'>Click here 1!</button>
  <div [innerHtml]="template"></div>
</template>
```

Which results in this:
I get to buttons in the view.
The first button which sends the message 1, prints out 1 to the console. The other button does however not print out any message.

I would like to keep to templatestring in the .ts file so how do i implement this so that the template can get a hold of the functions?

Comment: Can you provide plunker for the same?

Comment: What is `$implicit`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer from the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html): Note: using the key $implicit in the context object will set it's value as default. However it does not seem to be used in any valid way in the provided code.

Comment: It should be `<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: 'somecontextValue}">`

Answer (score 5):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

If you want to use a string that contains Angular2 specific syntax like binding, then you need to create a component at runtime where this string is used as components template. See also [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)

`$implicit` can be used like

```
<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: 'somecontextValue'}">
```

Then you can make `somecontextValue` available like

```
<template #report let-context>
  <div>{{context}}</div> <!-- outputs `somecontextValue` -->
</template>
```

Comment: I see :D No prob. Just update the correct question. You can delete the comments that are not related to this q+a.

Comment: I think might be missing a single quote, or added one accidentally.