# Extend ng-content Transclusion

Tags: angular

I want to make a `ng-content` template for a component. But I cant find a tutorial how to solve this.

I want that the syntax in my views look like this:

```
<slider>
    <img src="url" alt="alt">
    <img src="url" alt="alt">
</slider>
```

My `Slider` Component:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'flx-slider',
    template: `
        <section class="slider">
            <div class="slider-inner">

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <ng-content select="img"></ng-content>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </section>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./module.flx-slider.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class FlxSliderComponent {

    constructor() {

    }

}
```

I think all see the problem. At last it must be so, that it creates for every `img` an extra `li` around the `img`. Anyone can tell me, how I can do this?

Comment: You have to wrap every img with component knowing to display its content or not and communicating with `<slider>`. I'll create full answer with an example in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

You can use `<template>` with `<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="...">`

```ts
<slider [data]="['url1', 'url2']">
  <template let-data><img [src]="data" alt="alt"></template>
</slider>
```

```ts
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'flx-slider',
    template: `
        <section class="slider">
          <div class="slider-inner">
            <ul>
              <li *ngFor="let item of data">
                <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></template>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./module.flx-slider.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class FlxSliderComponent {
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef:TemplateRef;
    @Input()
    data:<any>[];
}
```

*not tested*

See also

- [Angular 2 bind transcluded content to loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41239733)
- [Angular 2 NgTemplateOutlet with string variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929931)
- [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844)
- [How to repeat a piece of HTML multiple times without ngFor and without another @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676593)

Answer (score 0):

You should use two components. One to iterate through the images, and one to use as a slider.

your final implementation code should look something like this:

```
<slider>
    <image-list [data]="['url1', 'url2']"></image-list>
</slider>
```

Slider Template:

```
<section class="slider">
    <div class="slider-inner">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</section>
```

List template:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">
        <img [src]="item.url">
    </li>
</ul>
```