# What is let-* in Angular 2 templates?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I came across a strange assignment syntax inside an Angular 2 template.

```ts
<template let-col let-car="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <span [style.color]="car[col.field]">{{car[col.field]}}</span>
</template>
```

It appears that `let-col` and `let-car="rowData"` create two new variables `col` and `car` that can then be bound to inside the template.

Source: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/templating

What is this magical `let-*` syntax called?

How does it work?

What is the difference between `let-something` and `let-something="something else"`?

Comment: @NiekT. this is different, let-* in angular 2 is template variable scoping

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template-input-variable search the word "let " (with a space) and go to around the 9th one. There is a good explanation of what this template variable does

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks for the correction, I'm quite new to JS and Angular myself.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also [CHANGELOG.md @ angular/angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01)

**original**

Templates (`<template>`, or `<ng-template>` since 4.x) are added as embedded views and get passed a context.

With `let-col` the context property `$implicit` is made available as `col` within the template for bindings.
With `let-foo="bar"` the context property `bar` is made available as `foo`.

For example if you add a template

```ts
<ng-template #myTemplate let-col let-foo="bar">
  <div>{{col}}</div>
  <div>{{foo}}</div>
</ng-template>

<!-- render above template with a custom context -->
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"
             [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                                           $implicit: 'some col value',
                                           bar: 'some bar value'
                                        }"
></ng-template>
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39929931/angular-2-ngtemplateoutlet-with-string-variable/41241329#41241329) and [ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createEmbeddedView).

`*ngFor` also works this way. The canonical syntax makes this more obvious

```ts
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index" let-odd="odd">
  <div>{{item}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

where `NgFor` adds the template as an embedded view to the DOM for each `item` of `items` and adds a few values (`item`, `index`, `odd`) to the context.

See also [Using $implict to pass multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523288/using-implict-to-pass-multiple-parameters/48524305#48524305)

Comment: Thanks for explaining `ngOutletContext`. That was the missing link between what I already knew and the information that I couldn't find in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think it is called `ngTemplateOutletContext` as you've suggested in the release of angular 5. The docs also don't mention anything about it being deprecated. https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: 5 is not yet released. Not sure what the docs show. The changelog doesn't have anything new about it since then.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, there is a strong lack of documentation on what the `*` syntax is doing.

Comment: Shouldn't be the second ng-template (the one with ngTemplateOutlet) really ng-template. Maybe ng-container would be better? Both will work I guess, but the ng-container is semantically more correct. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Between let is only supported in template element ;)

Comment: What does embedded view means here ?

Comment: @user8348978 I don't know in detail myself, but it's a part that is rendered by Angular and then the result inserted to the DOM. In this case for each item of `items`.

Comment: I still don't understand how I have `<ng-template let-banana>` in a template file, where banana doesn't exist anywhere in the controller, but there is an array `arrayStuff` that has a declared Type of say '<Fruit>', with values pushed into it in a forEach loop. yet somehow banana has the data of the array. 
There is no reference to banana in the controller. and no reference to arrayStuff in the template. Yet it works? How?!

Answer (score 2):

The Angular microsyntax lets you configure a directive in a compact, friendly string. The microsyntax parser translates that string into attributes on the `<ng-template>`. The let keyword declares a template input variable that you reference within the template.

Comment: As someone who really is struggling to understand this, this answer might as well be in latin.