# Primeng How get rowIndex of row expanded?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <p-dataTable [value]="services" [paginator]="true" expandableRows="true" rowExpandMode="single">
...</p-dataTable>
```

exists some like this

```
<ng-template let-col let-period="rowData" let-ri="rowIndex"   pTemplate="body">...</ng-template>
```

for DataTable

Answer (score 20):

In your ng-template for the expansion of row use the below code

```
<ng-template let-i="rowIndex">

   <button (click)="expand(i)"> expand </button>
</ng-template>
```

In the  button that is clicked during expansion use the below code to get the rowindex

```
expand(i){
    //... your logic to expand the row...
    this.expandedRowIndex = i;
}

 <p-dataTable [value]="services" [paginator]="true" expandableRows="true" rowExpandMode="single" (onRowExpand)="onRowExpand($event)">
```

Update 1: 
As you are clicking the entire row to be expanded. You can use the `onRowExpand` property of the `<p-datatable>` to achieve this.

```
onRowExpand(cc){
    console.log(cc)
    //logs the entire object which is clicked     
  }
```

This method is triggered when the row is expanded

[image]

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/8fUyK22LkMUfPP2BWOVp?p=preview)**

Comment: is this only way?

Comment: where put this inside <p-column expander="true"></p-column>

Comment: can you create a plnker?. how are you expanding  a particular row?

Comment: I have a column <p-column expander="true" styleClass="col-icon" [style]="{'width':'36px'}"></p-column> and in <p-dataTable> tag define that it es expandable, this mechanism work fine, but  I dont get the index of row expanded

Comment: **WHEN is the ROW EXPANDED**?? on click of something?

Comment: **WHEN click in row with attribute expander**, that  primeng works in feature expanded dataTable

Comment: on click of the complete row?

Comment: not, only in the column expander,
 https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/rowexpansion

Comment: In event.data is the  object of row, but that id not is the index of row, you can put in id:150 and you will see thar print 150 and the row is one. If {"id":1,"vin":"consequat metus sapien ut nunc ve ...."} id is 100 so print 100 not 1. I want index of row expanded

Comment: in that case you can find by comparing the id with the tableData object and get index using `findIndex` function. Can't you?

Comment: what id? how you can get id of dataTable, you only have id of object

Comment: `tableData object` only I meant see up. Also are you in a intention to argue or fix your issue

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: didn't want to start a new question, but how do I keep the absolute row index after sorting / filtering and not the table row index?

Answer (score 9):

```
<ng-template let-i="rowIndex" let-line pTemplate="rowexpansion">
```

`rowIndex` is probably added to `rowExpansion` now, works for me in latest version

Comment: This does the job. Excellent

Comment: may i know what rowIndex here please ?
is that a existing variable ?

Comment: @jaibalaji Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates

Answer (score 9):

You can use it:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-record="$implicit" let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
                        <tr [pSelectableRow]="record">
                            <td>
                                {{rowIndex + 1}}
```