# How to make use of let-* and ngTemplateOutlet to make dynamic listing in angular

Tags: angular, ngtemplateoutlet

I am looking into concept of ngTemplateOutlet to make dynamic listing system.

```
 <app-dynamic-list [items]="items">
    <ng-template let-item>
      {{ item.id }} - {{ item.names.en }} ({{ item.names.np }})
    </ng-template>
 </app-dynamic-list>
```

Here `let-item` should be an instance of `items`. What should I do in component level to get such. I read some post in stackoverflow but could not make clear concept (because they have static templateRef - and I donot want to have static templateRef).

[What is let-* in Angular 2 templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates)

[Using $implict to pass multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523288/using-implict-to-pass-multiple-parameters/48524305#48524305)

Similar code pattern is being used in - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-sortable

Answer (score 0):

In Order to create dynamic listing the projected content are accessed using @ContentChild Directive. So, that when they are projected the "CONTEXT" should be used as of HOST || Parent component from where they have been called.

**app-dynamic-list -> .ts file**

```
  @Input()
  items: Array<any>;

  @ContentChild('listItem', {static: false})
  dynamicListTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**app-dynamic-list -> .html file**

```
     <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;">
        <ng-container
            [ngTemplateOutlet]="listItem" 
            [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ item: item}">
        </ng-container>
      </<ng-container
```

So, When the the content are projected from parent component and the items are passed as @Input. Iterating each item and passing item object in **item** key which will be an object in this case and that item will be accessed using let-item in ng-template.

**note:** make sure @ContentChild('listItem'...) name should match with #listItem  defined in parent component  tag.
Therefore same template reference will be passed in **[ngTemplateOutlet]="listItem"** to tell angular which template to render dynamically as multiple templates can exist in host or child component.

```
<app-dynamic-list [items]="items">
// ContentChild Projected inside `app-dynamic-list` component
    <ng-template #listItem let-item>
      {{ item.id }} - {{ item.names.en }} ({{ item.names.np }})
    </ng-template>
 </app-dynamic-list>
```

Comment: I am trying out above solution. I got error - `Identifier 'listItem' is not defined.`.  I am doing this in angular 9