# How to Add ElementRef into local dom?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-ng-transclude, transclusion

I want to crate a layout component to arrange groups of items, like:

```
<garden-bed>
  <div #veg (click)="pluck()">carrot</div>
  <div #veg (click)="pluck()">cabbage</div>
  <div #veg (click)="pluck()">turnip</div>
</garden-bed>
```

The component so far looks like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-garden-bed',
  templateUrl: './garden-bed.component.html',
})
export class GardenBed  {

  @ContentChildren('veg') vegs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('this.vegs=' + JSON.stringify(this.vegs));
  }

}
```

but I can't figure out how to plant them in the tamplate (garden-bed.component.html):

```
  <div *ngFor="let veg of vegs">
     <ng-content/ng-template  *something="veg"></ng-template>
     but this doesn't work.
     veg should appear here and all its binding should work!

  </div>
```

any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid issues with change detection you should get the templateRefs out of the `QueryList` using `toArray` only once:

```
  templates: TemplateRef[];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('this.vegs=' + JSON.stringify(this.vegs));
    this.templates = this.vegs.toArray();
  }
```

then use `ngTemplateOutlet` to stamp the templat

```
  <div *ngFor="let veg of templates">
     <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="veg"></ng-container>
     but this doesn't work.
     veg should appear here and all its binding should work!

  </div>
```

`ngTemplateOutlet` also allows to pass context data that can be bound to in the template

See also

- [What is let-* in Angular 2 templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates/42978464#42978464)

Don't get confused by `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate"`, it's just alternate syntax to what I showed above

- [Empty context data of ng-template while implementing recursive ngFor loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834194/empty-context-data-of-ng-template-while-implementing-recursive-ngfor-loop/48834424#48834424)

Comment: thank you, it works! + <div #veg  should be <ng-template #veg otherwise it fails with SearchLayoutComponent.html:2 ERROR TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function