# Rendering the components in ContentChildren of Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, components

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { IconBoxComponent } from '../icon-box/icon-box.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-three-icon-box',
  templateUrl: './three-icon-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./three-icon-box.component.scss']
})
export class ThreeIconBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(IconBoxComponent) boxes: QueryList<IconBoxComponent>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.boxes);
  }

}
```

Its template looks like this:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
      <div *ngFor="let box of boxes" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 lz-mb-2 lz-mb-sm-0">
        {{ box }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm rendering it:

```
  <app-three-icon-box>
    <app-icon-box icon="#icon-one">content 1</app-icon-box>
    <app-icon-box icon="#icon-two">content 2</app-icon-box>
    <app-icon-box icon="#icon-three">content 3</app-icon-box>
  </app-three-icon-box>
```

In that second block of code, I'm trying to render the `<app-icon-box>`, but I can't figure out how.  `{{ box }}` was just an idea of what I'm trying to do, but I just get `[object Object]`.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 22):

You should use this pattern

1. Create TemplateMarker Directive to mark which [templates](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef) you want to pass as parameters (to prevent grabbing [other templates](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip#dynamic-content)).
2. Inject markers using `@ContentChildren`.
3. Render them where you need using [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet).

Hint: You can render each template multiple times and [send them parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates).

Example:

```
import { Component, Input, Directive, TemplateRef, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[templateMarker]'
})
export class TemplateMarker {
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'template-owner',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let marker of markers">
      <i><ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="marker.template"></ng-template></i>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TemplateOwner {
  @ContentChildren(TemplateMarker) markers: QueryList<TemplateMarker>;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<template-owner>
    <div *templateMarker>first template</div>
    <div *templateMarker>second template</div>
  </template-owner>`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {}
```

Answer (score 15):

It's a bit unclear what you need.
But I guess it would be enough to use ng-content. Remove the ContentChildren and also the ngFor and just use

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

In your template.

Then you have to add the classes directly where your box components are declared.

```
<app-icon-box class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-1 lz-mb-2 lz-mb-sm-0" icon="#here-to-help-you">
```

To enrich projected components within the ThreeIconBoxComponent you will need a totally different approach using templates and a template outlet.

Comment: `<ng-content>` has three elements in it, and I want to wrap each one in some HTML. I don't just want to spit out the HTML directly.

Comment: That's not possible this way. You could style the boxes by components scss with :host::ng-deep.

Comment: I want to keep the original `app-icon-box` components they way they are because they're being used elsewhere in different ways. I'm shocked that Angular doesn't provide a way to just render its child components.

Comment: I meant to style them fro the scss of ThreeIconBoxComponent.
This can be done by using 
:host::ng-deep {
    app-icon-box {
        // some styling
    }
}

Comment: @user1807782 What you want is called "Dynamic Content Projection" and is currently not possible, as David Ibl stated. There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was just asking this same question in an application I'm developing.

I'm unsure how "correct" my solution is but this is how I tackled this problem.

In my case my parent `component` is only supposed to accept content of a specific type (in your case this would be the `IconBoxComponent`).

Within that child `component` (`IconBoxComponent` here) I exposed a `TemplateRef` which can then be used by the parent `component` for rendering.

Although using a `directive` also worked I didn't like the idea of having to use both my custom child `component` as well as a custom `directive`.

**Note**: In my example below I removed all of the `CSS` `classes` and some `HTML` elements to make it more readable. They weren't removed for some technical reason.

##### IconBoxComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon-box',
  template: `
    <ng-template #template>
       <span>My Icon Box</span>
    </ng-template>
  `,
   styleUrls: ['./icon-box.component.scss']
})
export class IconBoxComponent {
  @ViewChild('template', { static: true }) template!: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

##### ThreeIconBoxComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-three-icon-box',
  template: `
     <div>
       <div *ngFor="let box of boxes">
         <ng-container
           [ngTemplateOutlet]="box.template"
         ></ng-container>
       </div>
      </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./three-icon-box.component.scss']
})
export class ThreeIconBoxComponent {
  @ContentChildren(IconBoxComponent) boxes = new QueryList<IconBoxComponent>();
}
```

##### Usage

```
<app-three-icon-box>
  <app-icon-box>content 1</app-icon-box>
  <app-icon-box>content 2</app-icon-box>
  <app-icon-box>content 3</app-icon-box>
</app-three-icon-box>
```