# Angular let-col let-item="rowData"

Tags: angular, primeng

I recently started to work on Angular 4 and while working on primeNG data table I came across a syntax like this `let-col let-item="rowData"`. I am confused what it is doing in my code and and why do I need 2 let-*'s. Can anyone please spare sometime and explain me the same?

```
<p-dataTable [value]="employees" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedEmployee" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [responsive]="true">
    <header>Employee Management Service</header>
    <p-column field="name" header="name" [sortable]="true">
     <ng-template let-col let-item="rowData">
       <label>some data</label>
     </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I did got through [What is let-* in Angular 2 templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates) but this did not cleared my doubts. And what will happen if I do {{col}} and {{item}}. Please guide.

Comment: anna i not sure what you trying to ask can you explain more

Answer (score 5):

`let-item="rowData"` in HTML is the equivalent of `let item = rowData` in Typescript

It's used in Angular templates `<ng-template>`.

`let-col` use the implicit declaration, which would be `let col = col`.

The variables `rowData` and `col` are declared by the primeNG module.

Comment: Why do you need `let-col` then? Isn't `col` already available at that point?

Comment: Why would it be available ?

Comment: If `let-col` is `let col = col` then isn't the `col` on the RHS available already?