# Angular "let-col" is not passing all the properties

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to pass extra fields to help with the processing. This how I define the columns array:

```
this.columns = [
        {field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', isMultiRowColumn: true },
        {field: 'year', header: 'Year', isMultiRowColumn: false},
        {field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', isMultiRowColumn: false},
        {field: 'color', header: 'Color', isMultiRowColumn: false}
    ];
```

Now, when I run the below code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="testData">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of columns" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header">
    <ng-template let-col let-dt="rowData" pTemplate="body">
     <span>{{dt[col.field] + '-' + col.isMultiRowColumn }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I'm getting this:

```
dsad231ff-undefined 2012-undefined  VW-undefined    Orange-undefined
```

Is there any reason `isMultiRowColumn` is not being passed?

Thanks for helping

Comment: did you added the </p-column> tag?

Comment: @EhsanKiani it was hidden when I pasted the code her. I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: remove let-col from ng-template.

Comment: @FatemeFazli. It worked. Now I'd like to understand. Is `let-col` different from `let col of..`? I'm a little confused about what can be defined in the `let-`.

Comment: With let-col the context property $implicit is made available as col within the template for bindings. and you chose the col var in ngfor same as let-col, so try to change your col var name like: ```*ngFor="let column of columns"``` and it will work.

Comment: when you define let-col it makes a new var that references the table col that has a field property and it doesn't references your col variable that is defined in ngFor, it has field property but not isMultiRowColumn property, so try to change your ngfor variable from col to something else like column.

Comment: Your array is `this.cols` but you are iterating in template `*ngFor="let col of columns"` shouldn't it be `*ngFor="let col of cols"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With let-col the context property $implicit is made available as col within the template for bindings. and you chose the col var in `ngfor` same as `let-col`,when you define let-col it makes a new var that references the table col that has a field property and it doesn't references your col variable that is defined in `ngFor`, it has field property but not `isMultiRowColumn` property, so try to change your `ngfor` variable from `col` to something else like `column`:

also check:
[What is let-* in Angular 2 templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates)

```
<p-dataTable [value]="testData">
  <p-column *ngFor="let column of columns" [field]="column.field" [header]="column.header">
    <ng-template let-col let-dt="rowData" pTemplate="body">
     <span>{{dt[column.field] + '-' + column.isMultiRowColumn }}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

see [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p-data-table-dynamic-forms-ts2fas) and click button and check the log in your browser to see what the col really is.