# How to access dynamically set inputs name property in an Angular form in the template

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, input

I wrapped an **ngx-datatable** component in a `form` tag so I can validate `inputs` in the table cells. Due to the nature of how the table is populated I set the inputs `name` properties dynamically

```html
<form #tableForm="ngForm">
  <ngx-datatable
    [rows]="_rows">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of rowDeffinition; let columnIndex=index">
          <ngx-datatable-column [prop]="column.key" [name]="column.label">
            <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
              <input
                class="cell-input"
                (blur)="updateCellValue($event, column.key, rowIndex)"
                type="text"
                [ngModel]="value"
                [name]="rowIndex + '-' + column.key"
              />

              ...

            </ng-template>
          </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ng-container>
  </ngx-datatable>
</form>
```

Normally, the `name` property would creates a local variable in the template and you can access the inputs control properties via the variable name.

```html
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required minlength="4" />
<div *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched">
```

I wonder how can I do this dynamically in the same manner I set the inputs name. So far I was able to access the input controls via the **form reference** but this becomes quite wordy

```html
<span *ngIf="!tableForm.controls[rowIndex + '-' + column.key]?.valid && 
      !tableForm.controls[rowIndex + '-' + column.key]?.pristine"
      class="[ c-validation-message ]">
  required
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your input in new component and you can access these generated components via `@ViewChildren(...)` in parent components `.ts` file:

```
@ViewChildren(NgxDatatableInput) datatableInputs: QueryList<NgxDatatableInput>;
```

I recommend to create method in parent component, which retrieves concrete datatableInput from `datatableInputs` by `name` as parameter. After that you can use this method in generated, new `ValidationSpanComponent`:

```html
<ValidationSpan [control]="getDatatableInput(dynamicName)">
</ValidationSpan>
```

Template of `ValidationSpanComponent`:

```html
<span *ngIf="!control.valid && 
      !control.pristine"
      class="[ c-validation-message ]">
  required
</span>
```

Comment: I could get the inputs control reference by using a function the whole time, but this is [considered to be a bad practice](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496#:~:text=To%20avoid%20issues%2C%20it%20is,pipe's%20input%20does%20not%20change). I am more seeking for a syntax which would allow me to access the declared variable. One solution may be [using a template and ngTemplateOutletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978082/what-is-let-in-angular-2-templates)

Comment: Tbh I dislike optimization just for the sake of optimization, since profits of it are minimal. I guess your proposed solution will be less readable than just creating new components and using `ViewChildren` : )

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44514238/1991697) I came up with following solution

```html
<form #tableForm="ngForm">
  <ngx-datatable
    [rows]="_rows">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let column of rowDeffinition; let columnIndex=index">
          <ngx-datatable-column [prop]="column.key" [name]="column.label">
            <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
              <!-- Helper template allowing to define few variables for more readable property binding-->
              <ng-template #cellContent [ngTemplateOutlet]="cellContent"              
                let-cellName="cellName" let-isValidInput="isValidInput" let-isPristineInput="isPristineInput"
                let-isRequiredInput="isRequiredInput"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{
                  cellName: rowIndex + '-' + column.key,
                  isValidInput: tableForm.controls[rowIndex + '-' + column.key]?.valid,
                  isPristineInput: tableForm.controls[rowIndex + '-' + column.key]?.pristine,
                  isRequiredInput: column.input?.required
                }">

                <input
                  class="cell-input"
                  (blur)="updateCellValue($event, column.key, rowIndex)"
                  type="text"
                  [ngModel]="value"
                  [name]="cellname"
                />

                ...

              </ng-template>
            </ng-template>
          </ngx-datatable-column>
        </ng-container>
  </ngx-datatable>
</form>
```

This improves the general readability vastly, since my table has a very complex logic, and i track the state of the cell in a structure like:

```js
interface EditTableRowStatus {
    editing: { [coolumnId: string]: boolean},
    changed: { [coolumnId: string]: boolean},
    addedRow: boolean;
  }

let rowsStates = EditTableRowStatus[]
```

which led to super complex property binding in the template

```html
<input
  class="cell-input"
  *ngIf="column.input?.type === INPUT_TYPES.TEXT && (rowsStates[rowIndex]?.editing?.[column.key] || rowsStates[rowIndex]?.addedRow)"
  [autofocus]="!rowsStates[rowIndex]?.addedRow || columnIndex === 0 "
  (blur)="updateCellValue($event, column.key, rowIndex)"
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="value"
  [ngClass]="{'has-changes': rowsStates[rowIndex]?.changed?.[column.key]}"
  [name]="rowIndex + '-' + column.key"
  [required]="column.input?.required"
/>
```

now becoming much more readable

```html
<input
  class="cell-input"
  *ngIf="inputType === INPUT_TYPES.TEXT && (isEditing || isAddedRow)"
  [autofocus]="!isAddedRow || columnIndex === 0 "
  (blur)="updateCellValue($event, column.key, rowIndex)"
  type="text"
  [ngModel]="value"
  [ngClass]="{'has-changes': isChanged}"
  [name]="cellName"
  [required]="isRequiredInput"
/>
```