# How to load multiple ng-templates dynamically with ngFor based on object property

Tags: angular, accordion, ngfor, ng-template

[Step1]
I have an object "article" which has an array of multiple content elements. Depending on the type of the element (eg. header/image), a different template should be shown. I don't want to explicitly have an own component for this, if not necessary, so I'm guessing whether ViewChild nor ContentChild is needed?

I have looked into all of the ngTemplate related questions, but havent found a solution yet.
I tried to rewrite https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1y2vz
from [ngTemplateOutlet with dynamic value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513603), but failed so far.

**component.ts**

```js
articles: any[] = [ {
    "id_seq": "1234",
    "content":[
      {
        "id": "123456",
        "order": 0,
        "type": "header",
        "data":
          {
            "text": "loremipsum"
          }
      },
      {
        "id": "234567",
        "order": 1,
        "type": "image",
        "data":
          {
            "url": "http://www.google.de/image.jpg"
          }
      }]
  }]
```

**component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of articles[0]?.content;">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content?.type">
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>


<ng-template #header >
  <p>I'm a header</p>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #image >
  <p>I'm an image</p>
</ng-template>
```

Depending on syntax and code placement of ngTemplateOutlet, I get an error

> templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function

or nothing is rendered at all.

If i type a static string like "header", it works. So I'm guessing, the content?.type is not the way to go. 
On the other hand, something like this works fine:

```html
<accordion>
  <accordion-group heading="articlecontent" [isOpen]="isFirstOpen">
    <div class="accordion_no_side_margin">
      <accordion-group *ngFor="let content of articles[0]?.content"
                       [heading]="content?.type">
        {{ content?.id }}
        {{ content?.order }}
        {{ content?.type }}
        {{ content?.data }}
      </accordion-group>
    </div>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

[Step2]
Ultimately I do want to merge both code snippets, so that the ng-template should be executed inside the accordion.

[Step3]
Later I intend to add ngTemplateOutletContext and provide some information, but the other steps should work just fine without that.

At the moment I'm using 
@angular-devkit/core 8.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it just did not wanted to work with ngFor for whatever reason, i tried ngSwitchCase, which works good enough and never looked behind since then
(although it would have been nice to have the templates/ng-containers on the outside)

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of localArticles[0]?.content">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="content?.type">

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'header'">
      <p>I'm a header</p>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'image'">
      <p>I'm an image</p>
    </ng-container>

  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what is about with `articles[0]?.content` in your code but try like that:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let content of articles[0]?.content;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="content?.type == header; then header; else image"></ng-container>
    <ng-template #header >
      <p>I'm a header</p>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #image >
      <p>I'm an image</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
```

try like this if above not work Your array are not loading:

```
<div *ngIf="articles | async as artic">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let article of artic">
    <ng-container *ngfor="let ar of article.content">

      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == header; then header; else image"></ng-container>
      <ng-template #header>
        <p>I'm a header</p>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #image>
        <p>I'm an image</p>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

If You have hard coded array You can remove `| async` pipe.

Answear to what You told me in coments:

```
<div *ngIf="articles | async as artic">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let article of artic">
    <ng-container *ngfor="let ar of article.content">

      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == 'header'"><p>I'm a header</p></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == 'image'"><p>I'm a header</p></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == 'pain in ass'"><p>I'm a header</p></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == 'love masturbating'"><p>I'm a header</p></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="ar.type == 'love dogs'"><p>I'm a header</p></ng-container>

    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, haven't seen this yet. But doesn't work unfortunately.
articles[0]?.content is just a workaround, because i don't have an article model defined yet and there is just one article in a local array.

Comment: I see what you did there (at least partly). The thing is, i have 10+ types (header & image are just examplatory), so using if/else is not really an option. Also what's the point of using ngFor 2 times...?

Comment: Becouse You have array in array ? Thats the point of 2x ngFor.

Comment: If You have 10+ types just use `*ngIf` for each one type. Like `*ngIf="type == header"` next one `*ngIf="type == image"` etc.