# How to make the ngTemplateOutlet dynamic in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code that I tried:
***HTML***

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="room"></ng-container>

<ng-template #room1>
   test 1
</ng-template>

<ng-template #room2>
    test 2
</ng-template>

<ng-template #room3>
     test 3
</ng-template>
```

***TS***

```
room = 'room1';
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the template based on the variable for example.
`room = 'room1'` then it will display only the template `#room1`.

But I'm getting an error which is this one: `Error: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by putting a condition in your `ngTemplateOutlet`. You can try either of these 3 methods below:

**Method #1**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="room === 'room1' ? room1 : room === 'room2' ? room2 : room3"></ng-container>
```

---

**Method #2:**

***HTML***

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="selectedRoom"></ng-container>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('room1') room1: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('room2') room2: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('room3') room3: TemplateRef<any>;

room = 'room1';

get selectedRoom() {
  const rooms = {
    room1: this.room1,
    room2: this.room2,
    room3: this.room3
  } 

  return rooms[this.room];
}
```

---

**Method #3 (the same as #2 but using conditional approach):**

***HTML***

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="selectedRoom"></ng-container>
```

**Component**

```
...

get selectedRoom() {
  return this.room === 'room1'
    ? this.room1
    : this.room === 'room2'
    ? this.room2
    : this.room3;
}
```

Attached herewith is a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xy9myv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference

Comment: Although the solution works, you don't need the `selectedRoom()` method. Setting `<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="this[this.room]"></ng-container>` is enough. And of course `strict` needs to be set to `false` in `tsconfig.json`, otherwise Angular will complain about a  million things.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your `component.ts` file

```
@ViewChild('room1', { static: false }) room1:TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('room2', { static: false }) room2:TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('room3', { static: false }) room3:TemplateRef<any>;
```

For more details [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513642/6810539)